# How to ORDER BY a JSON value?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-order-by

I have this column named "**data**" and has some JSON in it.

What i want to do is order my SQL query by the "**toptimes**" value.

My actual and desired query:

```
"SELECT core_members.pp_thumb_photo,name,member_group_id,data FROM game_accounts.accounts INNER JOIN website_accounts.core_members ON member_id = account_id WHERE member_group_id IN (4, 7, 8, 6) ORDER BY data ->> '$[0].toptimes' ASC LIMIT 100"
```

My JSON code:

```
[ { "daily_login": { "yearday": 56, "hour": 11, "second": 33, "minute": 18, "weekday": 3, "month": 1, "monthday": 26, "timestamp": 1582715913, "year": 120, "isdst": 0 }, "toptimes": 49, "daily_login_streak": 1, "hunters": 59, "playtime": 226099647, "awards": [ ], "nickname": "RandomNick" } ]
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. JSON functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: yes im using MySQL

Comment: Also: What if there are several elements in your JSON array?

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Bashar There are square brackets around the JSON, that makes it an array of objects. Presumably you made it an array so you can have multiple objects.

Comment: updated the post @Barmar shows the full code now

Comment: It's still an array of objects. What should happen when there are multiple objects in the array? If that can't happen, why is it an array in the first place?

Comment: the json only shows like that, I really don't know how to answer..

Comment: It's your data, don't you understand it structure?

Comment: @Barmar this data is coming from a game, im the webdeveloper and I'm supposed to use this data, but im only asking to learn more than I know

Comment: You should find out from the game developer how to use the data. They put it in an array for a reason, you need to understand the reason.

Comment: Is it coming from an API? Is there online documentation of the API?

Comment: So there is no solution..? @Barmar

Comment: I never said that. I said you need to understand what you're supposed to do, and if you want us to help, you need to explain it clearly.

Comment: The answer from GMB should work with the data as you showed it.

Comment: full sql query updated

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want:

```
order by data ->> '$[0].toptimes'
```

This will order the resultset according to the value of toptimes in the *first* element of your JSON array.

If you are storing a JSON *object* and not an array (although this is not what you showed in yuour sample data), then:

```
order by data ->> '$.toptimes'
```

Comment: sorry, i showed you only a part of my json code, I edited the post to show the entire code, your piece of code didn't work sadly

Comment: Just change `.kills` to `.toptimes`

Comment: @Bashar: I updated my answer accordingly (also see Barmar’s comment).

Comment: @Bashar: define *does not work*. Are you getting an error? Wrong results (how are they wrong)?

Comment: It just doesn't shows anything in my table, there is no errors btw, can't find a way why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something on these lines:

```
ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(data,'$.daily_login.toptimes)
```

Access `toptimes` through `daily_login` within the JSON object.

Comment: im really a beginner with this, I tried your code but it didn't work, I updated my JSON code by the way

Comment: is there a way to see why it doesn't work? it shows no rows in my table when I try your code

Comment: still doesn't work.. my table is showing everything but once i add your code to order it, the loop table shows no results

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem, only for MS SQL. It helped to convert a string to a number.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Uuid],
  JSON_VALUE(json, '$.likesCount') as likesCount,
FROM [dbo].[Playlists]
order by CONVERT(bigint, JSON_VALUE(json, '$.likesCount')) desc
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.